# Partial match a range of strings with another range of strings, outputting the partial match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to partial match the following range of strings:

[image]

against this range of strings:

[image]

and if there is a match, output the original values from the original range:

[image]

I've tried nested IFS and VLOOKUPS, which strangely didn't work for me:

=IF(VLOOKUP("*"&$B$1&"*",E1,1,FALSE)=E1,$B$1,IF(VLOOKUP("*"$B$2&"*",E1,1,FALSE)=E1,$B$1)

I've also tried:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1:B22,E1)))
```

Which got close, but it produced only digits for me in the end, when I want the original string from the 1st range I'm using.

I only want to use formulas, not script.

Answer (score 0):

Using your SUMPRODUCT construction and adding `"*"` before and after the search string and using it inside an index function:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$22,IF(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&$B$1:$B$22&"*",$E$1:$E$25))=1,ROW($B$1:$B$22),"")),"")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below formula and see if it helps your situation.

`=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH($B$1:$B$22,E1,1),$B$1:$B$22)`

Here 2^15 is a number larger than maximum number of characters that Excel cell can hold.

**Note:** I am sure about this formula in Excel. However, I have not tested this formula in google-sheets.